# Getting the IP Address of an Android Device using it's hotspot from another android device

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have two `android` enabled devices.On one device i turned on the hotspot and from other device i am connecting to that hotspot. Now i want to get the `IP` address of the first device. How can i get it. Because i want to send a file to the first device that's why i need the `IP` address of that device.I am assuming `WifiManager` will be used for this purpose but i don't know how. I read some other threads that are using `NetworkInterface` for this purpose.

-Usman

Comment: by first device, you mean the device on which you turned on the hotspot..?

Comment: Its has a fixed IP of `192.168.43.1` . It is hardcoded in android

Comment: I am not talking about hotspot ip address. i am talking about phone's ip address. because i want to send a file to that device.

Comment: They are of course the same. Or if they are not the same that of the device is 192.168.43.1.

Comment: `because i want to send a file to that device`. You want to send a file to a sever running on the device.

Comment: yes @greenapps i have a program running on one device on which hotspot is on and will be waiting for connections. then i want to send it a file from another android device using the ip address i get from the hotspot

Comment: @UsmanRiaz They are same man..! I have implemented this thing several times before. The Device gets the ip of the hotspot i.e. 192.168.43.1

Comment: @greenapps They are not the same i just saw. i get the ip address from wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress() and this was different from the device's ip address i saw from settings->wifiSettings>advance->ipAddress

Comment: can i send a file using that ip address. the one i get from getIpAddress() method ?? @greenapps

Comment: @greenapps It's 192.168.43.11

Comment: In android sdk its very clearly written that either of wifi, wifi-hotspot or wifi-direct will work at once. So when you switch on wifi-hotspot, then wifi is essentially off. Hence, going to wifi wifi-settings->advanced is not the right thing. Check [this](http://postimg.org/image/k9abv6j5p/) screenshot. Clearly, IP is unavailable when hotspot is on.

Comment: `can i send a file using that ip address. the one i get from getIpAddress() method ?? `. Why are you asking? Meanwhile you could have tried that a hundred times. If your code works in a usual wifi network it will work now too.

Comment: @unrealsoul007 Thanks i get it know. Can i communicate with that device using the hotspot ip address ???

Comment: @UsmanRiaz Yes you can... And happy to help! 
Plus if you find the comment useful please upvote it so that anyone reading in the future can refer to it.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
 for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) 
{
  NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();     
  for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses();enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) 
   {
     InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
     if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress())
      return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); 
   }
 }

}
 catch (SocketException ex) 
 { 
   Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
  }
```

Comment: I just  used wi.getConnectionInfo().getIpaddress() and it gives me the ip address not of device but the hotspot. does the above code gives the ip address of device??

Comment: android device those are connected to any Network give you the exact IP Address which the network have assigned to your device.